# XML Slurper how to check if element exists

Tags: xml, groovy

I have an xml document as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <s:Body>
    <Response xmlns="http://www.goo.com/2015/07">
      <Result xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      </Result>
    </Response>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Using Groovy xml slurper I do the following.

```
if (payload) {
    responsePayload = new groovy.util.XmlSlurper().parseText payload
}
```

That works and it passes all the elements with text. But I can't quite figure out how I can check for the existence of the Result element.

Is there a way I can do something like this?

```
responsePayload.Envelope.Body.Response.exists() or maybe check the size()?
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the `GPathResult` for `.Body.Response.Result` is empty:

```
responsePayload.Body.Response.Result.isEmpty()
```

That will returl `true` if there is no `Result` node found under `Response`, and `false` otherwise.

Edit to clarify this VS your expectation:
- `responsePayload` already represents the root element `Envelope`, so `responsePayload.Envelope` yields an empty result.
- `responsePayload.Body.Response.Result.isEmpty()` would always return `false` because this asks "are there any `Body > Response > Result` elements?", and not if the `Result` node has children or content.